# Can't get result from grep in bash loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to get info from log files using grep + tail -1:

```
#!/bin/bash
# declare an array called array and define 3 vales
array=( 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 )
array2=( 00 30 )
for i in "${array[@]}"
do
        for j in "${array2[@]}"
        do
                 output=$(grep filtered /home/pavel/hasoffers_api/logs/tabatoo2_20180627$i$j* | tail -1)
                 echo /home/pavel/hasoffers_api/logs/tabatoo2_20180627$i$j*
                 echo "$output"
        done
done
```

this outputs just empty string, but I definitely know that phrase "filtered" is in the logs.

What can be the problem?
I tried several variations of the same script but it just returns empty string.

Thanks!

Comment: I think the script looks ok. The only explanation I see is that the string "filtered" is not in the logs or there's no files named ".../tabatoo2_201806270000*". Without log files I/we can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Comment: Thank you for comments, the script is actually working well, the phrase was different, my bad. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this kind of assignment of a output value you should always redirect standard error (stderr) to standard out put (stdout). In your case if `grep filtered /home/pavel/hasoffers_api/logs/tabatoo2_20180627$i$j*` fails the error output will not be stored in variable `output` hence it will be difficult for you to debug the program. Change your script like below where error message will also be assigned to variable `output`.

```
output=$(grep filtered /home/pavel/hasoffers_api/logs/tabatoo2_20180627$i$j* 2>&1 | tail -1)
```

Now if search string is not available `echo $output` will print a empty string and if log file is not available it will print the error message

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

For start maybe try to test if the file you get by building string "tabatoo2_20180627$i$j*" even exists.